# If $\forall (u_m)_{m\in\mathbb N} \subseteq X$ s.t $\lim ||u_m|| = \infty $it follows that $\lim J(u_m) = \infty$ Then, $J$ is seq. weakly coercive

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, calculus-of-variations

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $X $be a reﬂexive Banach space and $J : X \to \mathbb R$ be a functional such that

$\forall (u_m)_{m\in\mathbb N} \subseteq X$ such that $\lim_{m\to \infty} ||u_m|| = \infty$ it follows that $\lim_{m\to \infty} J(u_m) = \infty$ $\tag 1$

Then, $J$ is sequentially weakly coercive.

**My try:**

-The definition of weakly coercive is that $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb R \forall (u_m)\subseteq X$ such that $J(u_m)\le \alpha$ implies $\exists u_{m_k} \rightharpoonup u $

-The contrapositive of stament (1):

$\text {If } \lim_{m\to \infty} J(u_m) < \infty \implies \lim_{m\to \infty} ||u_m|| < \infty \tag{2}$

Therefore let the hypothesis of the exercise hold and let  $\alpha \in \mathbb R$ and $(u_m)\subseteq X$ such that

$J(u_m)\le \alpha$

Taking the limit:

$\lim_{m\to \infty} J(u_m)\le \alpha$ which implies by (2), that $ L:=\lim_{m\to \infty} ||u_m|| < \infty $.  This means that

$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists M(\epsilon) $ such that $\forall m>M(\epsilon)$, $| ||u_m|| -L|<\epsilon$

$  \implies ||u_m|| <\epsilon +|L|$, which means that $(u_m)$ is bounded.  By a Corollary of Banach-Alaoglu, every bounded sequence in a reflexive Banach space has a convergent subsequence, so I have the thesis.

**1. Is this correct? If not, please enlighten me.**

**2. I am specially suspicious about taking the limit of $J(u_m)$ because I don't know if that limit exists, so I should just take a liminf or limsup I guess? But then I wouldn't know how to proceed.**

Comment: Yes, a priori we do not know if $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} J(u_m)$ exists, but you know that $(J(u_m))_m$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @stange why is it bounded? and how does that help?

Comment: Bolzano-Weierstrass seems like what @stange is getting at

Comment: Because you did assume that $J(u_m) \leq \alpha$. What do you know about bounded sequences in $\mathbb{R}$? (@Lorago already spoilered)

Comment: @stange Each infinite bounded sequence in  $\mathbb R$ has a convergent subsequence, as suggested by Lorago that means that I should continue working with the subsequence instead at that point?

Comment: Correct. And the rest of your proof looks good to me.

Comment: @stange Thanks a lot, if you want to post an anwser I'll be happy to accept it. Something else: I was doubting about the contrapositive of (1). I left out the quantificator, so I don't know if I should have keep it as $\forall$ or negate it and place it in the consequent of (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here a short answer. A priori it is not known if $\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty} J(u_m)$ actually exists. But since $J(u_m) \leq \alpha$ for all $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $(J(u_m))_{\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ and we may use Bolzano-Weiterstraß to extract a converging subsequence. 
Regarding your last comment, note that the contrapositive of a statement is not the same as the negation.

Comment: yeah What I meant is that the statement is of the form $\forall x p(x) \implies q(x)$ and the contrapositive I considered is ~$ q(x) \implies$~$p(x)$ but what happened with the quantifier? I just wrote what sounded good when read outloud, but formally to start with I am not sure if it meant  $(\forall x p(x)) \implies q(x)$ or $\forall x (p(x) \implies q(x))$. In the first case , the I am not sure what to do with the quantificator. In the second case, it would be ~$ q(x) \implies (\exists x $~$p(x))$

Comment: With contraposition the quantifier stays the same. Maybe this explains it better https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3852490/1155332.